# continue bash script after ctrl+c from while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, continue, ctrl

Is it possible to get out of a bashscript while loop with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and continue in the script instead of exiting it?
In my script I have a while function and an menu function. I want to re-run the menu function if <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed from the running while loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

function while_loop {
D=1
while [ "1" == $D ]
do
        sleep 5
        echo $D
done
}


function main_menu {
M="i"
while [ "$M" != "e" ]; do
echo -e "auto update:\ta"
echo -e "exit:\t\te"
read -n 1 M
case $M in
    a)  while_loop
        ;;
    e)
        exit 1
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Wrong input!"
esac
done
}

main_menu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like this

```
trap my_handler INT
my_handler() { D=0; }
```

The trap command allows you to intercept signals and add your own signal handling.

Comment: I think that the call to `sleep` is preventing this from working as expected.